# I can’t get my iOS project to build my changes

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm new to the iOS side of things and I’m having a huge issue. None of my changes I am making to my views are being built when I build iOS. I run

```
sudo cordova build ios
```

Then I open Xcode and “sign” it. I then run from Xcode to my test device. But no changes are made. Even when I remove the iOS platform, add it back, rebuild iOS, run from Xcode, my changes still have not taken effect in the build. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

After you update your view, the process is:
1. build the components and pages and copy the result into www dir.
2. copy the contents in www into ios project, with `ionic prepare` command.
3. build your ios project.

With the latest version of ionic, it will be done one one command `ionic cordova build ios`, but if you use some old version of ionic, maybe you need to run:

```
ionic  build
ionic cordova build ios
```